# Should you create a github repo/project for things as small as a useful function

Tags: github, repository

Is it appropriate to make a fully blown github project/repo for something that you believe would be useful to others, but is as small as a single function?

Comment: Did you end up using a Gist, @Jemar?

Comment: @David Yeup i ended up just making a Gist

Comment: If you decide to expand it later, start by gist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, something as small as a single function probably doesn't need to be made as a full repository. Instead, you could make it a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/), which is GitHub's way of sharing small snippets of code in a source controlled way that's similar to a repository.

Answer (score 3):

GitHub says that "Gist is a simple way to share snippets and pastes with others." On the surface, that might suggest that Gist is a better alternative to a project, for a "small useful" function.

A fuller answer probably involves answering "how useful is useful", as you described it? Furthermore, how much work does the function do? If you would be happy to describe the function as a "snippet" or a "paste", then by all means, use a Gist. If, on the other hand, you expect the function might be re-used by hundreds or thousands of others, and cut computational intensity in half, for example, then perhaps it deserves a project.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr - go with whatever works for you, (OSS) repos are cheap!

This is a good question, and I don't think it's as simple as a yes or no answer. When you look at how large (and small) projects use GitHub repositories and the Gist service, you might see how this may not be such an obvious answer:

A large project might be [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/), where each repo is essentially a mapping of an existing library into Maven land - that's all. They have 100s of repos for this.

An example of how Gists are used very effectively is [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/), for shareable [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) visualisations.

Another example that comes to mind is **npm**: where you have a range of huge to tiny libraries using GitHub repositories e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-positive, **actual** code here: [index.js](https://github.com/kevva/is-positive/blob/master/index.js)

As [Sindresorhus](https://github.com/sindresorhus) says re 'One-line node modules':

> tl;dr You make small focused modules for reusability and to make it
>   possible to build larger more advanced things that are easier to
>   reason about.

Also

> People get way too easily caught up in the LOC (Lines Of Code). LOC is
>   pretty much irrelevant. It doesn't matter if the module is one line or
>   hundreds. It's all about containing complexity. Think of node modules
>   as lego blocks.

via https://github.com/sindresorhus/ama/issues/10#issuecomment-117766328

ps [a GitHub Gist *is* a normal Git repository](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/)